# BULK INSERT inserts delimiter instead of default NULL value for empy field

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to use BULK INSERT to insert some rows:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newsequentialid(),
  Name NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
  CreatedOn DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
  CreatedBy NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT SUSER_NAME(),
  ModifiedOn DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  ModifiedBy NVARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

I'm inserting from a CSV file that has UTF8 encoding, commas for delimiters, and the LF for the line endings:

```
 ,Fizz,,,,,
```

My BULK INSERT statement looks like this:

```
BULK INSERT Foo 
FROM 'C:\foo.csv' 
WITH (CODEPAGE = '65001', FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' , ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a');
```

But the final field of the inserted row (ModifiedBy) has a value of ',' (the comma delimter:

```
49625A3B-DCF1-E611-8D73-B00594F7CD91    Fizz    2017-02-13 12:04:48.223 sa  NULL    ,
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I make BULK INSERT insert the final field as NULL (default value) instead of ','?

Comment: I see six commas there, the last one isn't required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without column names in the first line of the data file, or values for every position in the file, or a complete sample of all variations of lines in the data file, one has to either assume:

1. the row terminator should also include the field terminator, or
2. there is an unknown additional column in the data source that is not accounted for in the table.

It may be less common, but it is not rare for the field terminator to also be included in the row terminator. In fact, many of the [examples on MSDN for **`bulk insert`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx#Anchor_10) show the `fieldterminator` as the leading part of the `rowterminator`.

This solution assumes that the `rowterminator` is part of the `fieldterminator`, similar to the examples on MSDN:

```
bulk insert Foo 
from 'C:\foo.csv' 
with (
    codepage = '65001'
  , fieldterminator = ',' 
  , rowterminator = '0x2c0a'
  );
```

[image]

Comment: Although your solution renders the desired output, I understand it's mistaken. The problem's root cause is that the input has seven positions (for six commas) and your solution assumes this extra comma being part of the row terminator - for every and each row.

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu I think it may be a presumptuous to assume my solution is mistaken. You are assuming the input has seven positions, but there is **no basis to conclude whether it has seven positions or six positions** given that the file does not include column headers or values for every position. I can not say which is more likely, but many [examples on MSDN for **`bulk insert`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx#Anchor_10) show the `fieldterminator` as the leading part of the `rowterminator`.

Answer (score 2):

The last column of the table receives all the remaining data in the input line after the other columns are assigned, apparently without ever parsing. If you put 100 commas to the input line, you'll get 95 commas in the last column in the imported table (I verified this by a quick test). As Marcus also pointed out, you must have 5 delimiters for 6 column layout.

If you can't remove the extra field from the input file, you can use a format file for column mapping, to exclude the last column which is explained in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187908.aspx

If your input file indeed was intended for 6 columns, and the last delimiter is there by convention, that is, "there is a delimiter after each column" instead of "delimiters between columns", then @SqlZim's solution should work fine mostly. But then again you must be sure no white-space etc. is added after the last delimiter in a line (such as when manually editing) or else the import will fail for that row as it won't match the row delimiter characters. So, to be more fool-proof, I would again suggest using column mapping method, adding a dummy field definition for the last delimiter and skipping it during import.

Looks like Sql server intends to be flexible or choose not to lose the orphaned data, but causes more confusion than being helpful.

Comment: Enough said :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just count the commas...

Foo table has **six** columns, while the given input has **seven** positions.

The last comma is assumed to be the value for `ModifiedBy` column.

`Id`**,**`NAME`**,**`CreatedOn`**,**`CreatedBy`**,**`ModifiedOn`**,**`ModifiedBy`**,`?`**

The input `,Fizz,,,,,,`, with seven commas, will render `,,` for `ModifiedBy`.

Answer (score 0):

I think,you have few option.

i) change bulk insert method,instead use OPENROWSET or OPENQUERY.IT allow you to mention column name.Example link,

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1207/different-options-for-importing-data-into-sql-server/

ii) If i) is not acceptable to you then you can define "After insert" trigger on table where you can update modifiedDate to null again.

I think solution one is perfect.